# Getting questions that have a specific tag or tags?

Tags: support, api, questions, tags, api-v2.2

In the current API (2.1 and 2.2), how do you get questions that have a specific tag or tags?

EG:

1. All Stack Overflow questions asked in the past 2 months tagged 'ruby'?
2. All Stack Overflow questions asked in the past 2 months tagged 'ruby' and 'git'?
3. All Stack Overflow questions asked in the past 2 months tagged 'ruby' or 'git'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For questions tagged with **all** tags in a list (**AND operation**), use **the `/questions` path.**
For example:

[/questions#fromdate=2013-01-11&sort=activity&tagged=ruby;git](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#fromdate=2013-01-11&order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=ruby;git&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

~~~~~
For questions tagged with **any** tags in a list (**OR operation**), use **the `/search` path.**
For example:

[/search#fromdate=2013-01-11&sort=activity&tagged=ruby;git](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/search#fromdate=2013-01-11&order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=ruby;git&site=stackoverflow&filter=default&run=true)

Comment: Is there no way to do this with /questions/featured?

Comment: @DaImTo, Do what exactly?  Be specific and open your own question.  That path does accept a tag filter. It probably operates in `and` mode. Use more than one request for `or` searches.

Comment: ok thanks I didn't want to open another question when this one was similar.