# Using OR with featured questions

Tags: support, feature-request, api, questions, bounty

My question is similar to:  [Getting questions that have a specific tag or tags?](https://stackapps.com/q/3977/25791)

What I am trying to do is get a list of Featured questions within a list of tags.  I have tried using the following:

Note link to doc: http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/featured-questions

But when I add more then one tag it appears to be using **and** instead of **or**. I was unable to find an `or` operator as `;` appears to be and.

**Example 1:** Right now because there is a featured question tagged with [google-analytics](/questions/tagged/google-analytics) this will return correctly:
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/featured?order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=google-analytics&site=stackoverflow

**Example 2:** But I would also like to see any featured questions within the [oauth2](/questions/tagged/oauth2) tag.  This currently returns nothing because I am using both the `Google-Analytics` tag and the `oauth2` tag:
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/featured?order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=google-analytics;oauth2&site=stackoverflow

[The `/search` path](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/search) says:

> `tagged` and `nottagged` are semi-colon delimited list of tags. At least 1
>   tag in tagged will be on each returned question if it is passed,
>   making it the OR equivalent of the AND version of tagged on
>   /questions.

If I understand that correctly, `/search` uses **;** for `or` logic, but unfortunately doesn't let me search only on featured questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the API does not let you get "featured" questions (questions that have bounties) using `or` logic with the tag parameters.  That is, you cannot search for questions that:
Have a bounty **AND** (have *Tag-A* **OR** *Tag-B*)

It might make sense to **add a `hasbounty` parameter to [the `/search/advanced` path](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search).**

## Workaround:

In the meantime, since the number of featured questions is quite small (currently only 413 on Stack Overflow), just use multiple queries to [the `/questions/featured` path](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/featured-questions) to get what you want.

For example:

1. Query [/questions/featured?tagged=google-analytics&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/featured?tagged=google-analytics&site=stackoverflow)
2. Then query [/questions/featured?tagged=oauth2&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/featured?tagged=oauth2&site=stackoverflow)
3. Then combine the results and eliminate any duplicate questions.

Comment: Agreed that's the work around I am currently using. But I dislike spamming nice APIs with extra requests that I could get back in a single request.  I wanted to be sure I was understanding a limitation in the current workings of the API.  thank you :)