# How to pass multiple tags (OR between the tags) to the Stack Exchange Questions/Unanswered API

Tags: support, api, questions, unanswered

I am using [the `/questions/unanswered` API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/unanswered-questions) to try and get all **unanswered** questions, sorted by upvotes, and with the tags specified.

How can I pass multiple tags to the `/unanswered` route(s) using OR-logic between those tags?

For example: I want to look for *unanswered* questions with tags `Vm` OR `vmss` OR `azure-functions`.

I know that passing `tagged=c;java` will return only those questions with **both** tags as this is an **AND** constraint. I am looking for **OR** constraint.

If this API does not allow OR-ing the tags, then is there an alternate way of achieving this?

Comment: @Hans, thanks for replying. I am looking for stack exchange API that I can call from my app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting questions that have a specific tag or tags?](https://stackapps.com/questions/3977/getting-questions-that-have-a-specific-tag-or-tags)

Comment: @BhargavRao the api that you shared does allows OR between tags but it shows answered as well as unanswered questions.
I want all unanswered questions sorted by upvotes and allowing OR between tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, you could do this with [the `/search/advanced` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search).
But, due to [a bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288451/the-tagged-parameter-in-search-advanced-stack-exchange-api-seems-to-be-applying), that route does not OR its tags as it is supposed to.
Go and upvote [that bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288451/the-tagged-parameter-in-search-advanced-stack-exchange-api-seems-to-be-applying), and theoretically it will get fixed sooner.

For now, the workaround will require a little bit more work from your app:

1. Use the `/questions/unanswered` route <sup><sub>(or the `/search/advanced` route with `accepted=False`)</sub></sup> to query the tags **one at a time**.
2. **Merge** the results from step one, discarding duplicates.
3. **Sort** to taste.

For example, suppose I wanted the ***unanswered*** questions tagged either [unityscript](/questions/tagged/unityscript) OR [rate-limiting](/questions/tagged/rate-limiting).
I would do the following:

1. Fetch [`questions/unanswered?tagged=unityscript`<sup>(link)</sup>](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/unanswered-questions#pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=votes&tagged=unityscript&filter=!Pvz4gC456mSsezlBq5ccv1drEE*hBj&site=stackoverflow&run=true), paging as necessary.
2. That gets results like:

   ```js
   "items": [ {
       "tags": ["c#", "unity3d", "game-engine", "unityscript"],
       "owner": { "display_name": "Ahmed Zafar" },
       "answer_count": 1,
       "score": 7,
       "creation_date": 1432146724,
       "last_edit_date": 1432235001,
       "question_id": 30357724,
       "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357724/destroying-clone-destroys-all-clones",
       "title": "Destroying clone destroys all clones"
     }, {
       "tags": ["c#", "unity3d", "unityscript"],
       "owner": { "display_name": "Sora" },
       "answer_count": 2,
       "score": 4,
       "creation_date": 1425211434,
       "last_edit_date": 1425215933,
       "question_id": 28793306,
       "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28793306/unity3d-crash-after-switching-a-scene-containing-a-webcamtexture",
       "title": "Unity3d crash after switching a scene containing a webcamtexture"
     },
     //etc.
   ```
3. Fetch [`questions/unanswered?tagged=rate-limiting`<sup>(link)</sup>](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/unanswered-questions#pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=votes&tagged=rate-limiting&filter=!Pvz4gC456mSsezlBq5ccv1drEE*hBj&site=stackoverflow&run=true), paging as necessary.
4. That gets results like:

   ```js
   "items": [ {
       "tags": ["java", "spring", "spring-security", "oauth-2.0", "rate-limiting"],
       "owner": { "display_name": "aj.esler" },
       "answer_count": 5,
       "score": 14,
       "creation_date": 1334619572,
       "question_id": 10183168,
       "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183168/how-to-implement-rate-limiting-based-on-a-client-token-in-spring",
       "title": "How to implement rate limiting based on a client token in Spring?"
     }, {
       "tags": ["nginx", "rate-limiting"],
       "owner": { "display_name": "linbo" },
       "answer_count": 1,
       "score": 9,
       "creation_date": 1363835060,
       "question_id": 15538728,
       "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15538728/does-nginx-httplimitreqmodule-support-per-hour-day-week",
       "title": "Does nginx HttpLimitReqModule support per hour/day/week?"
     },
     //etc.
   ```
5. Merge the result sets, discarding any duplicate `question_id`s:

   ```js
   {
     "score": 7,
     "question_id": 30357724,
     ...
   }, {
     "score": 4,
     "question_id": 28793306,
     ...
   },
   //etc.
   {
     "score": 14,
     "question_id": 10183168,
     ...
   }, {
     "score": 9,
     "question_id": 15538728,
     ...
   },
   //etc.
   ```
6. Sort to taste:

   ```js
   {
     "score": 14,
     "question_id": 10183168,
     ...
   }, {
     "score": 9,
     "question_id": 15538728,
     ...
   }, {
     "score": 7,
     "question_id": 30357724,
     ...
   }, {
     "score": 4,
     "question_id": 28793306,
     ...
   },
   //etc.
   ```
7. Done!

Comment: I also started to do a workaround for my case using /search api. I am thinking which approach will work better for my case.

Comment: You're welcome.  Do you mean the `/search/advanced` route?  The plain `/search` route won't let you find unanswered questions easily.

Comment: I am using plain`/search` which gives both answered and unanswered questions and then using `(if is_answered == false)` to filter out the questions which have no answers.

Comment: I do not recommend such an approach.  For example, for the 3 tags you listed in the question, there are [7,332 total questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-machine+or+vmss+or+azure-functions), but only [2,605 unanswered ones](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/virtual-machine+or+vmss+or+azure-functions).  This means you would be loading 4,727 questions unnecessarily.